# What provisions exist to handle scooping when there are multiple reviews of research papers?

Tags: publications, plagiarism

**Point 1:** At my university, it's a practice (not compulsory) to submit our conference/journal paper first to a department where it is checked for plagiarism and quality. Then it's sent to professors in the university to confirm that they don't have any authorship problems with it (ie: that the student didn't copy one of their ideas, unacknowledged). It's only then that the student gets approval to send the paper to a conference (specifically [this one](http://ieee-ssci2018.org/)) or journal.

**Point 2:** A journal or conference has it's long procedure of reviews and only some papers get accepted. If rejected or un-published, the author can send it to another conference or journal and there's a similar lapse of time.

During both above situations, isn't it possible for someone else to [scoop](http://www.sciencesurvivalblog.com/phd_life/getting-scooped_2435) the idea? Does the academic community have any provisions to prevent a planned scooping? ie: Someone reviewing the paper purposely rejects it and during the time that elapses, publishes the same idea or allows one of his/her other students to publish the idea.

A teacher of mine says that it's because of these fears that she directly submits papers to conferences without going through the university's process. Also, the same reason she submits to conferences instead of journals, because the journal review process is much longer, increasing the scope of the idea being scooped.

So are there any safeguards? If I see my idea scooped somewhere, would it help if I can show proof that I had already submitted the idea at a conference and the paper was rejected? Will the person who supposedly scooped it, get blacklisted?

Comment: [Here's a case in point](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107067/85564). The 2 top-voted answers there have some good suggestions for the situation you describe.

Comment: Nice. That led me to this answer about the Dataverse network. Hope it's a viable and valid idea: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/23400/28042. Also some info on simultaneous release: https://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/40047/title/Simultaneous-Release/

Comment: Good find on both counts. Perfect for a [self-answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing to a number of journal and conference organizers, KDD and IEEE responded by saying that putting up a document on arXiv and then submitting the same document to one of their conferences or journals is ok. IEEE officially mentions it [here](http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/publish-with-ieee/author-education-resources/guidelines-and-policies/policy-posting-your-article/). There's also a nice answer [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/108251/28042).

UPDATE:
As of 2019, KDD no longer allows pre-prints on ArXiv due to their double-blind policy.
As of 2020, IEEE started their own archive named TechRxiv, and they still allow pre-prints on ArXiv and TechRxiv.